# is this django validation code too old to use 

Tags: python, django, validation

i find a django validation code  ,but i find it was written 3 years ago ,

so  is it too old to use?

has some better way to validation in django

this is the code :

```
class UserField(forms.CharField):
    def clean(self, value):
        super(UserField, self).clean(value)
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=value)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Someone is already using this username. Please pick an other.")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return value

class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    username = UserField(max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Repeat your password")
    email = forms.EmailField()
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label="Repeat your email")

    def clean_email(self):
        if self.data['email'] != self.data['email2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Emails are not the same')
        return self.data['email']

    def clean_password(self):
        if self.data['password'] != self.data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords are not the same')
        return self.data['password']

    def clean(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.clean_email()
        self.clean_password()
        return super(SignupForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

thanks

Comment: "old enough to use it" for what?  why would the age matter in the first place?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess you meant that it might be too old to use.

Comment: Is your concern that when you include this code it will not be compatible with the version of django you use? (you could specify what version you use, btw).  Are you instead asking "Is this code 'old enough' to be in the public domain, and I am free to copy and use it?'", Is there a specific issue you have encountered when you did try to use it? If so, what was the error message?

Comment: What happens when you tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is: don't.

I don't know if this was correct at the time and I'm not willing to test if it still works, but it looks really, really old.

It somewhat resembles the examples in the [fine docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/), take a look and you will be able to figure out what changed over the last 3 years.